# Find the percentage of task completed if the value is "Completed" , i need a macro code to calculate this percentage in the level 0 task

Tags: excel, vba

Need to find the percentage of task completed if the value is "Completed" , i need a macro code to calculate this percentage in the level 0 task FOR COLUMN D,E,F,G. DESPITE OF COUNT I need to calculate the percentage of task completion if the value is completed. This calculation need to happen for every task where it's llevel is 0

| WBS Number | Task Description | Level | Developed | Tested | ReadyForRelease | Completed (%) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Emails | 0 | 11 | 11 | 11 | 11 |
| 1.1 | Trigger Booking confirmation Email for Party | 1 | Completed | Completed | Completed | Completed |
| 1.2 | Trigger Booking Partial Payment Email for Party | 1 | Completed | Completed | InProgress |  |
| 1.3 | Trigger Booking Full Payment Email for Party | 1 | Completed | Completed | InProgress |  |
| 1.4 | Trigger Booking Cancellation Email for Party | 1 | Completed | Completed | InProgress |  |
| 1.5 | Trigger Booking ReScheduling Email for Party | 1 | Completed | Completed | InProgress |  |
| 1.6 | Trigger Booking confirmation Email for Event | 1 | Completed | Completed | InProgress |  |
| 1.7 | Trigger Booking Cancellation Email for Event | 1 | Planned | Completed | InProgress |  |
| 1.8 | Trigger Booking ReScheduling Email for Event | 1 | Planned | Completed | InProgress |  |
| 1.9 | Trigger Booking confirmation Email for Timeslot | 1 | Planned | Completed | InProgress |  |
| 1.10 | Trigger Booking Cancellation Email for Timeslot | 1 | Planned | Completed | InProgress |  |
| 1.11 | Trigger Booking ReScheduling Email for Timeslot | 1 | Planned | Planned | Planned | Planned |
| 2 | Site | 0 | 34 | 34 | 34 | 34 |
| 2.1 | As a Visitor, I want to see Waiver Page | 1 | Planned | InProgress |  |  |
| 2.2 | As a Visitor, I want to Signup Waiver as a Guest | 1 | Planned | InProgress |  |  |
| 2.3 | As a Visitor, I want to Signup Waiver as a Customer | 1 | Planned | InProgress |  |  |
| 2.4 | As a Customer, I want to verify my account and then I should be able to login | 1 | Planned | InProgress |  |  |
| 2.5 | As a Customer, I want to change the password | 1 | Planned | InProgress |  |  |
| 2.6 | As a Customer, I want to recover my password using reset password feature | 1 | Planned | InProgress |  |  |
| 2.7 | As a Customer, I want to my profile information by login to waiver | 1 | Planned | InProgress |  |  |
| 2.8 | As a Customer, I want to my Children information by login to waiver | 1 | Planned | InProgress |  |  |
| 2.9 | As a Customer, I want to view my previously signed waivers | 1 | Planned | InProgress |  |  |
| 2.10 | As a Visitor, I want to see Contact Us Page | 1 | Planned | InProgress |  |  |
| 2.11 | As a Visitor, I want to submit a query to PeekNplay | 1 | Planned | InProgress |  |  |
| 2.12 | As a Visitor, I want to receive a confirmation email | 1 | Planned | InProgress |  |  |
| 2.13 | As an Admin, I want to receive a confirmation email when a customer submits the Query | 1 | Planned | InProgress |  |  |
| 2.14 | As a Visitor, I want to signup for a Newsletter Subscription | 1 | Planned | InProgress |  |  |
| 2.15 | As a Visitor, I want to receive a confirmation email for Newsletter | 1 | Planned | InProgress |  |  |
| 2.16 | As an Admin, I want to receive a confirmation email when a customer signs for an email Newsletter | 1 | Planned | InProgress |  |  |
| 2.17 | As a Visitor, I want to see Party Booking Page based on CRM Data | 1 | Planned | InProgress |  |  |

```
Sub CountLevel1TasksInLevel0()
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim Level0Row As Long
Dim TaskCount As Long

' Find the last row in the worksheet
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

' Initialize the variables
Level0Row = 0
TaskCount = 0

' Loop through the rows to count Level 1 tasks in Level 0
For i = 2 To lastRow
    If Cells(i, 3).Value = 0 Then
        ' If Level 0 is encountered, check if there were Level 1 tasks in the previous Level 0
        If Level0Row > 0 Then
            ' Place the count in Column D (4th column)
            Cells(Level0Row, 4).Value = TaskCount
            ' Place the count in Column E (5th column)
            Cells(Level0Row, 5).Value = TaskCount
            ' Place the count in Column F (6th column)
            Cells(Level0Row, 6).Value = TaskCount
            ' Place the count in Column G (7th column)
            Cells(Level0Row, 7).Value = TaskCount
            TaskCount = 0 ' Reset the task count
        End If
        Level0Row = i ' Set the Level 0 row
    ElseIf Cells(i, 3).Value = 1 Then
        ' If Level 1 task is encountered, increment the task count
        TaskCount = TaskCount + 1
    End If
Next i

' Check if there were Level 1 tasks in the last Level 0
If Level0Row > 0 Then
    ' Place the count in Column D (4th column)
    Cells(Level0Row, 4).Value = TaskCount
    ' Place the count in Column E (5th column)
    Cells(Level0Row, 5).Value = TaskCount
    ' Place the count in Column F (6th column)
    Cells(Level0Row, 6).Value = TaskCount
    ' Place the count in Column G (7th column)
    Cells(Level0Row, 7).Value = TaskCount
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Count "completed" and multiply by 33.333 for a percentage. round up to the next integer ie 34, 67 or 100.

Comment: Hi Mike, I am looking for a macro code to calculate this when I run a button.  The below code is generating the count but I want to calculate the percentage based on task status completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this workaround :

```vb
Sub CountLevel1TasksInLevel0()
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim Level0Row As Long
Dim TaskCount As Long

' Find the last row in the worksheet
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

' Initialize the variables
Level0Row = 0
TaskCount = 0

' Loop through the rows to count Level 1 tasks in Level 0
For i = 2 To lastRow
    If Cells(i, 3).Value = 0 And Level0Row = 0 Then
        ' If Level 0 is encountered, check if there were Level 1 tasks in the previous Level 0
        Level0Row = i
    ElseIf Cells(i, 3).Value = 1 Then
        ' If Level 1 task is encountered, increment the task count
        TaskCount = TaskCount + 1
        If Cells(i, 4) = "Completed" Then col4 = col4 + 1
        If Cells(i, 5) = "Completed" Then col5 = col5 + 1
        If Cells(i, 6) = "Completed" Then col6 = col6 + 1
      ElseIf Level0Row > 0 And Cells(i, 3) = 0 Then
            ' Place the count in Column D (4th column)
            Cells(Level0Row, 4).Value = col4 / TaskCount
            ' Place the count in Column E (5th column)
            Cells(Level0Row, 5).Value = col5 / TaskCount
            ' Place the count in Column F (6th column)
            Cells(Level0Row, 6).Value = col6 / TaskCount
            ' Place the count in Column G (7th column)
            Cells(Level0Row, 7).Value = (col4 + col5 + col6) / (TaskCount * 3)
            TaskCount = 0 ' Reset the task count
            Level0Row = i ' Set the Level 0 row
            col4 = 0
            col5 = 0
            col6 = 0
  End If
Next i

' Check if there were Level 1 tasks in the last Level 0
If Level0Row > 0 Then
    ' Place the count in Column D (4th column)
            Cells(Level0Row, 4).Value = col4 / TaskCount
            ' Place the count in Column E (5th column)
            Cells(Level0Row, 5).Value = col5 / TaskCount
            ' Place the count in Column F (6th column)
            Cells(Level0Row, 6).Value = col6 / TaskCount
            ' Place the count in Column G (7th column)
            Cells(Level0Row, 7).Value = (col4 + col5 + col6) / (TaskCount * 3)
End If

End Sub
```